# POST REST request body and bind it with response content in SOAPUI

Tags: json, rest, groovy, soapui

JSON request body is:

```
{
    "username": "admin"
    "password": "admin"
}
```

Mock JSON response body:

```
{
    "username": "admin"
    "password": "admin"
    "token-id": 123
}
```

I need to POST response like above binded with request body like above.

Do I need to use a Groovy script to do this? Can someone help me with this?

Comment: Yes, You can use groovy to do that. You need to parse the request using Groovy and modify the response on the fly.